# Integral of $\int\int{\sin(x-y)dxdy}$

Tags: integration, jacobian

I'm trying to calculate this integral :
$$\int_{D}\int{\sin(x-y)dxdy} $$
where $D=${$(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le1$}
,I've changed the parameters to:
$$x(u,v)=r\cos(\theta+\frac{\pi}4),\ y(u,v)=r\sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}4)$$
and finally I got stuck at the integral: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}|r|\sin(-\sqrt2r\sin(\theta))drd\theta$$ which I believe is very hard to solve.

Can anyone help?

Comment: hint: Set $r=x-y$,$R=x+y$

Comment: what are the limits on the original double integral?

Comment: $\sin(x-y)=\sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y$

Comment: Umberto, unit circle $x^2+y^2\le1$

Comment: Guys, i don't understand how these clues help in this problem.

Comment: @CodeHoarder: the contribute given by $(x,y)$ and the contribute given by $(-x,-y)$ cancel out, so the integral is simply zero.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of an odd integrable function over a symmetric (with respect to the origin) domain is always zero.